# For conferences with an abstract deadline shortly before full paper deadline, does the "no simultaneous submission" rule include abstract submission?

Tags: conference, paper-submission, abstract

It's generally forbidden to submit the same paper at two different venues at the same time. In addition, many computer science conferences have two different submission deadlines: a deadline for the submission of abstracts, followed by another deadline (1-2 weeks later) for the submission of full papers. A complete submission consists of an abstract and the accompanying paper.

Let's say we have a situation that involves two conferences, A and B:

- Conference A had its abstract and paper submission deadlines some time in
  October. A's website says that acceptance notifications will be sent
  to the authors on December 7.
- Conference B has its abstract submission deadline on
  December 1 and its paper submission deadline on December 8.

Is it OK to submit a paper to A and an abstract to B simultaneously, cancelling the submission to B in case the paper is accepted at A?

(It surely seems advisable to ask the conference chair of B, but since I know the chair of B personally, I don't feel comfortable asking, since this might come off as a request for favouritism.)

Comment: **Ask the PC chairs.**

Comment: Just to add that this is field dependent. Apparently in CS, conferences papers are more like regular papers. In biological sciences it's generally ok to submit similar abstracts in different conferences, as most of the times there is no "full paper" format to be provided later.

Comment: @Leon Meier This sounds more like a practical issue, rather than a moral one. In my particular case, the odds of that happening are very low, since the PCs do not overlap. (The paper is about applying a B-type-of-thing to an A-type-of-problem.)

Comment: Indeed, that's why I said "very low" rather than "zero".

Comment: That's the first time I ever hear of an obligation to have a straight answer to that question. I think it's perfectly possible to care about the target venue, but to not have a straight answer to that question: the same paper can be equally interesting for different audiences and communities.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I agree that this is valid argument against submitting the abstract to B, even if I'm not sure if it's a moral one, as it seems to be about not hurting people's feelings - strategically a good idea, but not necessarily morally.

Comment: @LeonMeier: "a common reviewer who gets the paper in both A and B" - to my knowledge, abstract deadlines shortly before the actual submission deadline are generally used for the organizers to get an idea of what topical expertise must be available among the reviewers. Reviewers are not actually learning about the papers at that point. My greater concern would be that, after a rejection from A, the authors have only one day until the submission to B, which will only allow for very minor changes (maybe legitimate, but maybe looked down upon by some).

Comment: @Leon Meier In my case, even if the paper had exactly the same set of reviewers, a rejection at A would not automatically imply a rejection at B, since A is a more selective conference than B.

Comment: @Leon Meier Sure, but if the general assessment is "good paper, but not good enough for A" (which is my worry), then this would imply a bias in favor of acceptance at B.

Comment: @Leon Meier Yes, if the reviews from A went into this direction, I would perhaps cancel the submission to B anyways and put more work into the paper before resubmitting. But I assume the paper is good.

Answer (score 4):

To answer this question, let's recall **why** many journals and conferences do not allow multiple submissions. So,

> Is it OK to submit a paper to A and an abstract to B simultaneously, cancelling the submission to B in case the paper is accepted at A?

- Multiple submissions are beneficial for authors, since they generally increase the chances for a paper/talk to be accepted and/or reduce the time until acceptance.
- However, this strategy is not beneficial for journals/conferences, since each venue will spend time and resources on processing the submission (register and peer-review it), and only one journal/conference will eventually publish it. The efforts spent by reviewers of another journal/conference will be wasted.
- This strategy is also damaging for the community of researchers. Firstly, peer-reviewers and editors are also academics, and they do not have much time to spare, so it is best not to waste it with pointless review process. Secondly, and more importantly, readers generally benefit from well-written and well-edited papers, and this relies on careful and time-demanding peer-review process. Faster acceptance may indicate better organised peer-review process, but it can also mean that the process is superficial (like it is in predator journals and such). By preferring a faster route, one can waste time of highly professional reviewers and also rob himself of a chance to get their valuable advice and improve their paper/talk accordingly.

So the answer is no - it is **not OK**.

Comment: This answer accurately describes the drawbacks of simultaneous submission in general, but I'm not sure if it addresses the specific situation here. Unlike regular submissions, abstracts submitted to conference B will not be subject to a standalone peer-review process - rather, the abstract is an "entry ticket" for submitting a full paper which will be subject to peer review. So I'm not sure if the argument of wasted effort still holds.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper Conference B sets up two deadlines. It is only natural to assume that they are going to do something in between (if not - what's the point of separating them?) It may not be peer review, but it should be some processing of abstracts.

Comment: Usually, the time between the deadlines is used to assign reviewers to papers. I think the added human effort is close to zero, since the submissions are processed automatically by a conference system, and the reviewers will at this stage pick their preferred abstracts based on interesting keywords, rather than read all abstracts.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper Conference B asks authors to submit abstracts, not just keywords, for peer review. It is natural to assume that reviewers are encouraged to read abstracts, not just keywords. It may work differently in practice sometimes, but we shouldn't rely on this.

Comment: B will have a least 50 abstracts, based on its earlier acceptance rates and paper numbers. In this case, I think it would be unrealistic to assume all reviewers to read all abstracts. But I see that some reviewers might in fact do so, so that's a small (still, from the purist point of view, prohibitive) bit of evidence speaking against submission of the abstract.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper I don't see where are you going with it. Maybe not all reviewers read all abstracts, but some reviewers still have to read your abstract. If you only use conference B as your plan B, you're going to waste their time.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov My point is: I agree that some time waste is involved, but I'm not sure if the amount of time waste is so large that anyone will care. From my (limited) experience as PC member, the time spent on each individual abstract is minimal, and it seems normal that not all submitted abstracts are followed by a paper.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov: "Conference B asks authors to submit abstracts, not just keywords, for peer review" - if we go by the OP's words (and this matches my experience), B does *not* ask authors to submit abstracts *for peer review*. B asks authors to submit abstracts. "It is natural to assume that reviewers are encouraged to read abstracts, not just keywords." - it is not clear that reviewers are involved at this stage at all. In fact, it would be somewhat unlikely that possible reviewers could be invited, sent material to review, and made to answer within a mere one or two weeks. Instead, ...

Comment: ... chances are titles (and keywords, which are often requested along with the abstracts) are used by a program chair to sort the expected submissions into one out of various thematical buckets for the upcoming peer review, and if title and keywords are not sufficient, they will have a superficial glance at the abstract to perform the categorization.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper In my area, authors self-assign their submissions to given thematical buckets, so there is no extra effort for the organizers. On the other hand, at least in the cases where I was involved, the PC members were allowed to read the submitted abstracts before the full paper deadline.

Answer (score 1):

There are particular conferences where the "no simultaneous submission" rule is refined so that it explicitely does not apply to abstracts. For instance, the [European Joint Conferences on Theory and Practice of Software (ETAPS)](http://www.etaps.org/2017/call-for-papers) have the following policy:

> Submitted papers must be in English presenting original research. They must be unpublished and not submitted for publication elsewhere (this does not apply to abstracts).

Unfortunately, for the conference B that motivated this question, this is not the case.

Comment: I think that it would be (maybe) OK if conference A included such a clause, not B. I say "maybe" because depending on how it is phrased, it could mean either "it doesn't matter if you submitted this work in a venue where you only submit an abstract (e.g. a workshop or a poster session)" (aka "abstracts are not publications"), or "it doesn't matter if you never submitted more than an abstract about that work (even if the abstract will later become a full publication)".